# What is the Mr. Grizz statue supposed to be? (Spoilers)

Tags: splatoon-3

After beating the main game, the Grizz statue in the Salmon Run lobby changes.

[image]

So what is it supposed to be? A narwal? It's definitely not a bear anymore but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal Mr. Grizz statue is a bear eating a fish. The post-game statue is a fish eating a bear, presumably meant to evoke the image of Hugefry from the final boss sequence.

Comment: Think its the antenna in the middle that really threw me off lol